# Linq select - handle situation where out of bounds exception would be thrown

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Does anyone know of a way I can write this expression to return an empty string where the length of the array is less than `ii`

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < maxColumnLength; ii++)
{
    var rowDataArray = columnData.Select(x => x[ii]);
}
```

I know I can write this as a for loop, but I am trying to do it in this style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you check with a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for the condition and select the appropriate item

```
var rowDataArray = columnData.Select(x => ii >= x.Length ? "" : x[ii]);
```

In this case if the condition is met take the first and if not the the second element.

From the documentation:

> The syntax for the conditional operator is as follows: 
>   `condition ? consequence : alternative`

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (var ii = 0; ii < maxColumnLength; ii++)
        {
            var rowDataArray = columnData.Select(x => ii < x.Length ? x[ii] : string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)